# Как правильно верстать горизонтальный список (меню)?

Tags: html, css

Имеется пример списка:

```
<ul>
<li><a>Пункт меню 1</a></li>
<li><a>Пункт меню 2</a></li>
<li><a>Пункт меню 3</a></li>
<li><a>Пункт меню 4</a></li>
<li><a>Пункт меню 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Как правильно записать стили, чтобы сделать горизонтальное меню?

Просто есть вариант с `float: left;`, `displat: inline;` итп. Хочу увидеть, как делают это профессионалы.

---

UPD: при `li` > `display: inline-block;` у li появляются боковые отступы, которые никак не могу убрать, а чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можешь глянуть в сторону `flexbox`

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/189118/ здесь есть ответ про отступы

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пример с `flexbox`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 0.9375rem;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navbar ul li {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Пример с `flow-root` & `float: left`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 0.9375rem;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flow-root;
}

.navbar ul li {
  padding: 1rem;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Upd**: Выделил `li`, сделал без отступов.

Comment: Благодарю, шикарный ответ!

Comment: @MikeRo, надеюсь он вам помог

Comment: Конечно, до этого было куча методов, как именно верстать то и то, а  на данный момент увидел, как сделал профессионал и сразу все сомнения отпали! Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @MikeRo, если мой ответ вам помог(а он помог), то отметьте решением.
P.S. я не профессионал:)

Comment: странно, в какой раз кликаю 'решение', а после возвращения на страницу, решение уже НЕ решение... P.S. ОК! =)

Comment: @St1myL, сколько в тебе энергии)))))

Comment: @Air, я хотел 3й пример написать, но подумал, что не окупит:)

Comment: В каком смысле не окупит?

Comment: @Air, по репутации:)

Answer (score 4):

Это один из вариантов....  `flex`.  Вот, что-бы не приходилось правиь ответ надо сразу в вопросе отмечать что да как надо

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(205, 115, 12, 0.1);
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
}

li {
  width: 19%;
  background: green;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Пункт меню 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Пункт меню 2</a></li>
  <li><a>Пункт меню 3</a></li>
  <li><a>Пункт меню 4</a></li>
  <li><a>Пункт меню 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

обычно `li{display: inline-block}`
но если вам надо будет,чтобы значение list-style было отлично от none,тогда вам надо использовать `li {float: left}`
в зависимости от адаптива,можно так же использовать flex или display: table, display: table-cell

чтобы избавиться от отступов инлайн-блоков,задайте им `font-size: 0;`
а контенту после задайте нужный размер шрифта

Comment: т.е. `float: left` это не ужасный вариант исполнения?

Comment: @MikeRo если вам нужно горизонтальное меню с list-style: square под IE9 , то вариант очень даже ничего,как мне кажется.